# Click event with object inside another function with event object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, keyup, backbone-events

I have a code like this and it's working, it activates on `click` and `keyup`:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .item": "clicked",
        "keyup .item": "keyupped"
    },
clicked: function(a) {
    var $item = $(a.currentTarget); ...}
keyupped: function(a) {
    var $item = $(a.currentTarget); ...}
```

But I would like to make `keyup` to work only with <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> and I can't get it to work. This is the idea I have, but I can't explain to myself what the event object a represents. In the simple function, it works. But in something like this, it doesn't:

```
keyupped: function(q) {
    if(q.which == 13 || q.which == 32) {
        function(a) {var $item = $(a.currentTarget); ...}
```

I don't understand the event object. I understand that in the `keyup` function it contains `keycode` data, but what it represents as a whole?

How should I write my keyupped function?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I don't know if this is the best practice, but it is working.

```
keyupped: function(q) {if(q.which == 13 || q.which == 32) {
        this.clicked(q);
    }},
```